# Play two files in VLC dummy and give sout parameters to both of them

Tags: command-line, audio, video, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player

I want to add multiple files to VLC's web interface. And the commands below do exactly that. Two files are added to the VLC's web interface's playlist.
But as you can see, that's not all I wanted - there are parameters after "sout" which tell VLC to stream these two files to my STB.

If I use this command, two files are added to web interface playlist, but only the "f24.ts" understands, that it needs to be sent to STB. When I play "K2.ts"
STB won't show this file:
`"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" -I dummy --dummy-quiet --extraintf=http --http-password testing --directx-volume=0.00 "C:\Users\user\Videos\K2.ts" "C:\Users\user\Videos\f24.ts" :sout=#duplicate{dst=udp{mux=ts,dst=239.9.14.2:1234},dst=dummy} :no-sout-rtp-sap :no-sout-standard-sap :sout-all :ttl=1 :sout-keep`

And when I use the same command, but switch file places, then "K2.ts" works, "f24.ts" doesn't:
`"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" -I dummy --dummy-quiet --extraintf=http --http-password testing --directx-volume=0.00 "C:\Users\user\Videos\f24.ts" "C:\Users\user\Videos\K2.ts" :sout=#duplicate{dst=udp{mux=ts,dst=239.9.14.2:1234},dst=dummy} :no-sout-rtp-sap :no-sout-standard-sap :sout-all :ttl=1 :sout-keep`

This means that only the second file gets the "sout" parameters, that it needs to be sent to STB's 239.9.14.2:1234 address. But I want **both** files to understand, that when I play them in my web interface, then it has to be sent to the STB's address specified in the sout.

Thanks for the help!
(same topic is also on VideoLAN forum: https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=119438)

edit: Googled for "vlc transcode multiple files" and [found this](https://wiki.videolan.org/How_to_Batch_Encode/). There's a command:
`for %%a in (*.VOB) do "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc" -I dummy -vvv %%a --sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=1024,acodec=mp4a,ab=192,channels=2,deinterlace}:standard{access=file,mux=ts,dst=%%a.mpg} vlc://quit`

I altered it for my case, made bat file containing.  But this loads only first ts file alphabetially, puts it to a web playlist:
`for %%a in (*.ts) do "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc" -I dummy --dummy-quiet --extraintf=http --http-password testing --directx-volume=0.00 %%a :sout=#duplicate{dst=udp{mux=ts,dst=239.9.14.2:1234},dst=dummy} :no-sout-rtp-sap :no-sout-standard-sap :sout-all :ttl=1 :sout-keep`

When I kill the VLC process, then it automatically starts with the second file. So it pretty much waits the previous file to get done. But I'm wondering if there's a way to "do" two files simultaniously.